# Journey Builder email change

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I made a change to a content block and link within an email.  Went to journey builder and did the update/edit sequence so that the email would update.

Looked into the tracking report and it looks like the change didn't take.
Am I doing something wrong here?  This is what SFMC says to do: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232320&type=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Email Studio > interactions > triggered sends

You will find the triggered send for your Journey under the Journey Sends folder - but be aware if you have multiple versions of a journey as you will want the most recent version.

Within the version folder you will find a triggered email for each email in the journey.

Pause the triggered email, then click Publish Changes and then restart the triggered send once again.

Your changes will apply to the journey email.

Answer (score 2):

I have observed that just selecting the email again in the send email activity doesn't  update the journey.

Instead of that, hover over the Email Activity and click on the view/update activity. 
From the "Select Email" tab select a different email and click next. 
A popup will appear to overwrite email. click yes.
Then Click on the back button to go back to the "Select Email" tab and select the actual updated email that you want in the Journey Builder and click next. Click overwrite changes and save the activity. This will ensure that the updated email will be used.